# Error adding to wallet. TypeError: FileSystemWallet is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

i have the written the chaincode and for that to interact with the frontend like express.js i need to add identities of the organizations of which peer i need to interact and i am getting the below error when i try to add identites

```
Error adding to wallet. TypeError: FileSystemWallet is not a constructor
TypeError: FileSystemWallet is not a constructor
    at Object.main [as execute] (/home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/1_addToWallet.js:14:20)
    at /home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/index.js:25:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at /home/sujan/hyperledger/fabric-samples/application/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:137:5
```

i am using fabric2.2

```
'use strict';

/**
 * This is a Node.JS module to load a user's Identity to his wallet.
 * This Identity will be used to sign transactions initiated by this user.
*/

const fs = require('fs'); // FileSystem Library
const { FileSystemWallet, X509WalletMixin } = require('fabric-network'); // Wallet Library provided by Fabric

async function main(certificatePath, privateKeyPath) {
  try {
    // A wallet is a filesystem path that stores a collection of Identities
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(`./identity/org1`);
    const certificate = fs.readFileSync(certificatePath).toString();
    const privatekey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath).toString();

    // Load credentials into wallet
    const identityLabel = `org1_admin`;
    const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(`org1MSP`, certificate, privatekey);

    await wallet.import(identityLabel, identity);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error adding to wallet. ${error}`);
    console.log(error.stack);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}


module.exports.execute = main;
```

i want to add identities to perform the transactions in the fabric network and the above is my code
this is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "NodeJS Application Accessing The testnet chaincode on Fabric Network",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "rm -rf identity && node index.js"
    },
    "author": "sujan",
    "dependencies": {
      "cors": "^2.8.5",
      "express": "^4.18.2",
      "expressjs": "^1.0.1",
      "fabric-client": "~1.4.4",
      "fabric-network": "^2.2.0",
      "js-yaml": "^3.12.0",
      "pug": "^3.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "eslint": "^5.6.0"
    },
    "license": "ISC"
  }
```

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? Clearly, `FileSystemWallet` is not what you expect, so have you tried looking at what `require('fabric-network')` is, since that’s where you destructure `FileSystemWallet` from, unquestioned?

Answer (score 0):

With fabric-network v2.2.x you need to use:

```js
const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
const identity: X509Identity = {
    credentials: {
        certificate: certificatePEM,
        privateKey: privateKeyPEM,
    },
    mspId: 'MSPID',
    type: 'X.509',
};
await wallet.put('org1_admin', identity);
```

The following resources will help you:

- Node SDK v2.2 API documentation, including client code example on [this page](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.html).
- [Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-wallet.html) on using wallets.
- [Writing your first application](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/write_first_app.html) guide (for Fabric v2.2) walking through the [asset-transfer-basic](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-2.2/asset-transfer-basic) sample.

Having said all that, if you can use Fabric v2.4 or later instead, I would recommend using the newer [Fabric Gateway client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/) instead, and using the following learning resources:

- [Running a Fabric application](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) guide (for Fabric v2.4+), which is an update to the *Writing your first application* guide above.
- [Full stack asset transfer guide](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide#readme) in the Fabric samples repository.